# Reveal File in Source Control (VS Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to reveal an open file in the source control side bar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is modified and the SCM bar is visible (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>) the SCM bar follows the current file in the editor.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to move focus to SCM bar and the current file has focus.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1..9</kbd> to move focus to one of the editors.